# Use 3d object as marker in 3d scatter plot - Python

Tags: python, matplotlib

With the below code, I'm trying to model a bowl built out of cans. I would like for each marker to be a can, what would be the best way to go about this?

I'd really appreciate any suggestions, thanks.

```
    import pylab
    import numpy as np
    from math import pi, sin, cos
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

    numCansHigh = 24
    startCanNum = 15
    hCan = 41
    dCan = 85
    rCan = dCan/2.0

    # Rise options: 0,1,2,3

    baseRise = 3
    topRise  = 2
    changeH = 8

    z = np.linspace(0, hCan*numCansHigh, num=numCansHigh)

    n=[startCanNum]
    for i in range(1, changeH):
        n.append(n[i-1] + baseRise)
    for i in range(changeH,len(z)):
        n.append(n[i-1] + topRise)

    r = [i*rCan/(pi) for i in n]

    theta = [2*pi / a for a in n]

    totalCans = 0

    for i in range(len(z)):
        for j in range(int(n[i])):
            totalCans+=1
            x9 = r[i]*cos(j*theta[i])
            y9 = r[i]*sin(j*theta[i])
            z9 = z[i]
            ax.scatter(x9,y9,z9,s=500,marker='s')


    plt.show()
```

Comment: Using `mayavi` is probably the best way to go, it uses `openGL` to render so can do 'proper' 3D.

Comment: Thanks tcaswell, I'll check it out now. This is for Canstruction - google if you're curious.